# Need help to deserialize xml data using c# datacontract deserializer

Tags: c#, xml, datacontract, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize XMl using Datacontract deserializer.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Invoice>
 <Samples>
    <Sample>
      <AccountId>1e547ae6-9a6d-d18f-958b-22000b83a845</AccountId>
      <AccountNumber>55761598808</AccountNumber>
    </Sample>
     <Sample>
       <AccountId>1e547ae6-9a6d-d18f-958b-22000b83a845</AccountId>
       <AccountNumber>55761598808</AccountNumber>
    </Sample>
  </Samples>
</Invoice>
```

I have defined the below classes to deserialize

```
        [DataContract(Name = "Sample", Namespace = "")]
         public class Sample
         {
             [DataMember(Name = "AccountId")]
             public string AccountId { get; set; }
             [DataMember(Name = "AccountNumber")]
             public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
         }

         [DataContract(Name = "Samples", Namespace = "")]
         public class Samples
         {
             [DataMember(Name = "Sample")]
             public List<Sample> Sample { get; set; }
         }

         [DataContract(Name = "Invoice", Namespace = "")]
         public class Invoice
         {
             [DataMember(Name = "Samples")]
             public Samples Samples { get; set; }
         }

   And the test method to deserialize
    [TestMethod]
    public void SampleXmlTest()
    {  
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\SJuluru\Desktop\Sample      XML\Samplexml_Modified.xml";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,  FileMode.Open);
        XmlDictionaryReader reader =
        XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CommonAvidXmlDto.Invoice));
        CommonAvidXmlDto.Invoice deserializedInvoice =        (CommonAvidXmlDto.Invoice)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
        reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
     }
```

When I ran the method in debug mode,  deserializedInvoice object got null and no data from XML is copied. Please suggest me a solution to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see where you have problems in deserialization is to *serialize* an example of your class and compare the result with the expected result.  For example, if I create an `Invoice` as follows:

```
        var invoice = new Invoice 
        { 
            Samples = new Samples { Sample = new List<Sample> { new Sample { AccountId = "1e547ae6-9a6d-d18f-958b-22000b83a845", AccountNumber = "55761598808" } } } 
        };
```

This serializes to the following XML:

> ```
> <Invoice xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>     <Samples>
>         <Sample>
>             <Sample>
>                 <AccountId>1e547ae6-9a6d-d18f-958b-22000b83a845</AccountId>
>                 <AccountNumber>55761598808</AccountNumber>
>             </Sample>
>         </Sample>
>     </Samples>
> </Invoice>
> ```

As you can see, there's an extra level of `<Sample>`nesting.  Thus your intermediate `Samples` class is unnecessary.  You can deserialize your XML using `DataContractSerializer` with just the following two classes:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Sample", Namespace = "")]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AccountId")]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "AccountNumber")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Invoice", Namespace = "")]
public class Invoice
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Samples")]
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Excellent..Thank you for the explanation:)

Comment: @julurusriharish - if the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).